# TYPO3 12: Set TypoScript constant as integer

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

So I'm currently updating a TYPO3 website from v11 to v12 and I've run into a problem I can't seem to fix. In my fluid template I'm generating a filter form using AJAX. To do that I'm assigning the AJAX PageType to the form. Since the number I'm setting is used in multiple places, I have a constant defined for it.

Since updating to TYPO3 12 I'm getting the following error:

```
TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Web\Routing\UriBuilder::setTargetPageType(): Argument #1 ($targetPageType) must be of type int, string given
```

Here's part of my code:
**HTML**

```
<f:form action="list" method="GET" name="overwriteDemand" pageType="{settings.tx_t8_references_ajaxpage}">
```

**TypoScript constant**

```
plugin.tx_t8references {
    ajaxPage = 427592
}
```

**TypoScript setup**

```
plugin.tx_t8references {
    settings {
        tx_t8_references_ajaxpage = {$plugin.tx_t8references.ajaxPage}
    }
}
```

Here's the output I get when using `<f:debug>{settings.tx_t8_references_ajaxpage}</f:debug>`:
[image: Debugger output]

How can I make it so that the constant I've set is of type integer?

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it working, when you do not use the constant and instead put the pagetype in directly? `pageType="427592"`

Comment: If so. Then you could implement your own small custom ViewHelper, that converts the string to an int.

Comment: Yes, setting the pagetype directly works. Thanks for your suggestion, I will try that out once I get back to my workstation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above. This is a bug in the FormViewHelper. Until the bug is fixed you could do the following:

EXT:vhs comes with an convert ViewHelper.

https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/vhs/blob/development/Classes/ViewHelpers/Variable/ConvertViewHelper.php

If you dont want to install vhs you could copy the ViewHelper to your own extension.

Answer (score 2):

this has been reported as issue, see https://forge.typo3.org/issues/100338 and is fixed. I guess you are not on the latest released version?

Comment: I'm actually on the latest version, 12.4.4 so it should be fixed. Might have something to do with the typo3 envirnoment set for the update. I will look further into it.

Comment: I think this is because the FormViewHelper you use is not fixed with the reported error. The FormViewHelper does not extend the Uri.ActionViewHelper or Link.ActionViewHelper. Instead the FormViewHelper handles the Arguments by itself.
I updated the issue.

Comment: And reported a new Bug: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/101486

Comment: which has been resolved as well, you can use either the dev version, patch your installation or wait for the next release! thanks a lot for the report!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `fluid` node expression converter, for example

```
{myvariable as integer}
```

or for the ViewHelper example from the question:

```xml
<f:form
    action="list"
    method="GET"
    name="overwriteDemand"
    pageType="{settings.tx_t8_references_ajaxpage as integer}"
>...</f:form>
```